# SuiteScript Cannot find function marshal in object [object Object]

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am writing a script in SuiteScript 2.0 where I pass a function to a different module to use, in order to decouple functionality between the two. The functions of the modules seem to work fine together but when I call search.create on an ad-hoc saved search I got "Cannot find function _marshal in object [object Object]" error, I have no idea what this is. I tried passing in the scope using call and that had no affect but the shared functions between the modules are fine. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you add a snippet? Is the "search" object coming from a "define" or "require" that is loading the search module?

Comment: yes, I have a common header that I use that I load things like search, runtime,file modules from, it said my code was too long to post. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: But it is a normal define/require listing of common libraries. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also received this error using a search.create, but it was because I was passing in an object instead of a single value for the internal ID.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the loading of multiple common modules like search etc, was causing the problem. By centralizing the access to the different modules seemed to have stopped the error. Also, side note, by getting rid of global objects like shared arrays between the modules seemed to make the code run quite a bit faster.